# Facebook App won't work if website not defined

Tags: php, jquery, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the plugin [Like 2 Unlock for jQuery](http://codecanyon.net/item/like-2-unlock-for-jquery/2822035).

I'm creating WP plugin and adding this plugin to lock some settings content.
When liked, it will be unlocked and people able to manage settings.

The facebook App need the website added to the Facebook App for it to work. Since this is going to be WP plugin, it will be hosted on others people domains. Well, in this case it will not work because their domain won't match with my domain in FB app.
Do the facebook app settings have something where you don't need to specify your website and this way no need to be tied to a specific domain?

Comment: have you tried checking out their support page? http://support.onepress-media.com/

Comment: yes, I did. Didn't find anything

Comment: have you checked the Facebook Developer pages?

Comment: yes, I did check their sites.

Answer (score 3):

Like Gating is not allowed and not possible anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> You must not incentivize people to use social plugins or to like a Page. This includes offering rewards, or gating apps or app content based on whether or not a person has liked a Page. It remains acceptable to incentivize people to login to your app, checkin at a place or enter a promotion on your app's Page. To ensure quality connections and help businesses reach the people who matter to them, we want people to like Pages because they want to connect and hear from the business, not because of artificial incentives. We believe this update will benefit people and advertisers alike.

Comment: I will offer free wp plugin and they will just like my page

Comment: that´s like gating, and it´s not allowed anymore. you can tell the user that he CAN like your page, but you would still need to give away the free wp plugin even without the like.

Comment: "This includes offering rewards, or gating apps or app content based on whether or not a person has liked a Page." - that´s pretty clear.

Comment: remember, people should like something because they really want to, not just because you offer them something in return.

Comment: well, they will like the page of the wp plugin they really like. What is strange about it?

Comment: it´s not "strange", it´s just not allowed anymore to force it, that´s all ;)